# How are new things added to the replicator?

Tags: star-trek, replicator

In any series of Star Trek using this technology, **how are new items--food-related or not--added to the replicator database for future replication**? Couldn't find anything on [StarTrek.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130926024221/http://www.startrek.com/database_article/replicator) or the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replicator_%28Star_Trek%29).

Is there an official procedure involving some sort of program where you name and describe what it is before adding a sample? Or is it more of a "here ya go" type of insertion? Can you only give a partial list of ingredients and tell the machine it needs certain extra things to be complete (give it beef, then specify it also needs a bun, lettuce, tomato, and Miracle Whip)?

If there are differences in procedure between generations, I'd like to know those as well.

Don't care about canonicity.

Answer (score 14):

The implication is that you can create new dishes from a combination of the 4500 *existing* ingredients by making a "program"

> **JANEWAY:** *Now you tell me. You go for authenticity and what do you get? Second-degree burns. **I've been slaving over that replicator
> programme for hours.** What was this bizarre rumour I heard about half
> the crew on deck five getting pregnant?*
>
> <sub><sup>[VOY: The Voyager Conspiracy](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/608.htm)</sup></sub>

Completely new items can be *scanned* into the database

> **MARTUS:** *I didn't, exactly. I just told the replicator to scan the original and make copies. I think they have some kind of internal
> power source.*
>
> <sub><sup>DS9: Rivals</sup></sub>

Comment: Is there a way to label and store it when scanning, or is that a one-time deal for immediate copy purposes? How do you tell it that a hamburger is called a hamburger?

Comment: @SonOfSam - I'm honestly not sure. I would imagine you could just put a (real) hamburger in it and the ship would scan it and produce something that's essentially identical. If you want to get clever and ask it to add  a slice of tomato, that's where the programming skill would come into it since you'd need to use ReplicatorShop (like Photoshop, but for replicators) to move the ingredients around to physically make space for it.

Comment: Never thought I'd hear someone say that adding a tomato was considered clever. :) I'm surprised this hasn't been touched on in the shows at least once, considering how often it's used. It seems like we'd've seen it even in the background.

Comment: @SonOfSam - Any fool can download a simple ["Hamburger Wireframe"](https://vidyow.com/video/Modeling-a-realistic-Hamburger/AqKBnmADw38/) for Blender Modeling Software, but if you want to do something as adding an extra slice of cheese, it takes hours (if not days) to learn how to do it.

Comment: Well when you put it that way...

Comment: @sonofsam You just tell it. Federation computers have amazing natural language processing capability.

Comment: @T.J.L. Is there an example of this anywhere? Valorum's answer doesn't specify whether or not any setup was required for the copies to be made. Or is that a separate function that only stores a temporary to make copies of?

Comment: @sonofsam Federation computers also have amazing storage capacity. You tell them what to do, and they do it. If you tell them to store something, they store it. Does it come up specifically for replicators on screen? No, but it doesn't have to. The capabilities of Federation computers are clearly shown in every episode. There are references to quantum vs molecular storage that explain why you can't replicate people, but that's an orders-of-magnitude situation.

Comment: @T.J.L. Well I was wondering what specific process there was. We could probably assume it really is that easy, but the **how** is what I was curious about.

Comment: Go look for questions on transporters. Replicators are just very small (or very large, for industrial units) transporters with a save function and no external emitters.

Answer (score 11):

It's often mentioned that foods can be programmed into the replicator, but never (to my knowledge) with details as to *how* that programming takes place.  In addition to @Valorum's quote, there's an instance in "Lessons" where Nella programs several varieties of tea into the replicator.

> NELLA: Earl Grey? No wonder you can't sleep. Computer, bring replicators back online and give me a cup of Daren herbal tea blend number three, hot. You shouldn't be drinking a stimulant at this time of night. I think you'll like this.
>   ...
>   NELLA: I've programmed seven other blends into the replicator. You're bound to like one of them.
>   PICARD: I look forward to sampling them.
>   [The Next Generation Transcripts - Episode Listings, "Lessons"](http://chakoteya.net/NextGen/245.htm)

We *do*, however, have some idea how holographic programs are made.  Were we to enter the realm of conjecture, we might note that:

> Holographic programs could be stored on holodeck databases. ... These databases often contained many stock elements that could be called up by a user to design new holographic programs, such as particular eating establishments, famous cities, and characters.
>   [Holographic Program - Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Holo-program)

We also see characters creating and modifying holodeck programs through verbal interaction:

> JANEWAY: Computer, display Fair Haven character Michael Sullivan. Adjust his parameters to the following specifications. Give him the education of a nineteenth century third year student at Trinity College.
>   COMPUTER: Modification complete.
>   JANEWAY: Now, access the character's interactive subroutines. Make him more provocative.
>   COMPUTER: Specify.
>   JANEWAY: Give him a more complicated personality.
>   COMPUTER: Specify.
>   JANEWAY: More outspoken, more confident, not so reserved. And make him more curious about the world around him.
>   COMPUTER: Modification complete.
>   JANEWAY: Good. Now, increase the character's height by three centimetres. Remove the facial hair. No, no, I don't like that. Put some back. About two days' growth. Better. Oh, one more thing. Access his interpersonal subroutines. Familial characters. Delete the wife.
>   COMPUTER: Modification complete.
>   JANEWAY: Pleased to meet you, Mister Sullivan.
>   [The Voyager Transcripts - Fair Haven](http://www.chakoteya.net/Voyager/610.htm), [Fair Haven clip on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mNCybqmKugA)

We might then extrapolate that replicators function similarly - they have a database of known foods and food components, and new dishes can be created by incorporating and modifying those existing elements via *Star Trek*'s highly sophisticated verbal interface.  Which is essentially what @Valorum said.

Comment: I saw this but my thought was that she'd simply taken these programs from a central archive and transferred them to their personal replicator under the heading of "drinks".

Comment: @Valorum - Hm, interesting thought.  It's possible that she accessed a central archive located somewhere besides the ship.  From the dialogue, those teas did not exist in the Enterprise's computers, so she programmed them in.  I always assumed she had the required technical knowledge to do so.  Perhaps creating a replicator program is akin to creating a holodeck program - the computer has a voice interface which will interpret one's commands and produce a result based on that.

Comment: @Mary7678: So she had to teach the replicator how to make a decent cup of tea?  That seems a bit Douglas Adams to me.

Comment: @Kevin - Sorry, I don't know what "a bit Douglas Adams" means.  I agree it seems odd that the replicator wouldn't have enough varieties of tea for someone's liking, but people often complain about replicated food, even when multiple varieties of a food are programmed into the replicator. "[F]ourteen varieties and they can't even get plain tomato soup right." - Tom Paris in Caretaker.  It would make sense to give people the ability to add both foods that do not exist and variations of food types that do.

Comment: @Mary7678: In the hope you're not pulling our legs about "a bit Douglas Adams": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Not_entirely_unlike  :)

Comment: @straycat - That makes so much more sense!  Thanks!!!

Comment: I'd personally regard the Nella programs as being like programming a VCR.  Not coding software programming.